# Add hash to a filename, then replace references to it using Gulp

Tags: html, css, gulp

I have the file `base.css`, and I have a `styles.php` file with the following code:

```
wp_enqueue_script('base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/base.css');
```

How can I have Gulp rename base.css with its hash and replace the reference in `styles.php`?

So, I'm looking for the file to be called e.g. `base-375dfd5f.css` and `styles.php` to read

```
wp_enqueue_script('base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/base-375dfd5f.css');
```

Comment: I would look at the way the [roots/sage](https://github.com/roots/sage) starter theme goes about revving assets. They use [`gulp-rev`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) to write to a manifest and then, within wordpress, read the json. This has the benefit of keeping everything related to the build in the dist/build folder.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen hashing plugins the write to a manifest, but I thought the intermediate stage of writing to the json file was a bit clunky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a [Gulp rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) pipe in your stream for the css name, and then use [Gulp inject string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject-string) for the update on the PHP file.

Something like this should work:

```
 var gulp   = require('gulp'),
     rename = require('gulp-rename'),
     inject = require('gulp-inject-string');

 var myHash = someLogicToGetThisValue();

 gulp.task('CSSHash', function () {
        return gulp.src('base.css')
                .pipe(rename('base' + myHash + '.css'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./')
 });

 gulp.task('PHPHashInject', function () {
        return gulp.src('file.php')
                .pipe(inject.replace('base.css', 'base' + myHash + '.css'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./')
 });
```

Comment: Yes, I'd seen that, but of all the hashing plugins I'd seen, none gave you access to the hash itself. One or two of them wrote the hashes to a manifest file. I could have created something myself using node's crypto, but I was surprised there wasn't something out of the box. I did find something though, so will post an answer myself.

Answer (score 2):

I found [gulp-cachebust](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cachebust) that does what I want: it renames files with a hash, then replaces references to those files with the hashed filenames.

### Update

I ended up using gulp-rev to create a manifest and change filenames, and gulp-rev-replace to change references to the files. It works well.

Comment: Jason you may want to give [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) a try. It is feature rich and the preferred tool as of now. You can use it to bust the cache and to rev you dev and release builds. That's how I use it anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Wilmer I did look at gulp-rev, but it writes to a manifest so then I'd have to go in and retrieve the original names and the hashed names from there, then replace those references within `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Comment: oh goodness, I forgot you were doing that. I don't add my references manually ever. Use [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject). Run your inject task first and then run your rev task. That will allow you to add script files at will, and not have to remember to maintain your references. I have hundreds, so imagine the nightmare if I were to do that manually